# All questions concerning ubuntu have been asked?

Tags: discussion

Could we arrive at a situation where all possible questions concerning ubuntu would have been asked and the corresponding answers given?
The questions that would not have been answered are those that are either poorly asked or are duplicates?

Comment: Even if that could ever happen, there would still be more fun to discover on the other sites of the network.

Comment: Don't forget about Murphy's law ;-)

Comment: New versions of Ubuntu have new features, and users always have new problems. Just like we will never run out of programming questions on [so].

Answer (score 6):

No. New versions keep coming out and bringing with them new problems. Also, the set of possible tasks one might want to use their OS for is essentially infinite. Yes, we can reach a point where all the obvious, classic questions have been asked but the set of on topic questions is, for all intents and purposes, infinite.

Comment: As well as new hardware.

Comment: @terdon what a good answer!!!

Comment: And new features and new bugs

Comment: and new users who bring new perspectives ....

Comment: And new ways to use rename to rename files.